# How run query in laravel where clause without table column name?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

**How can I make this query in Laravel**,  i m new in laravel

```
 Product_Type::addSelect([
            'p_name' => Product::select('p_name')->whereColumn('products.id','product_types.products_id'),
            'product_types.pt_name',
            'sale_qty' => Stock::selectRaw('SUM(stock_value)*-1')
                ->whereColumn('stocks.product_types_id','product_types.id')
                ->whereRaw('stock_value < 0')
                ->where('stock_type','sale')
                ->whereBetween('stock_date',[$reqFromDate,$reqToDate])
                ->whereIn('id', Bill::select('stocks_id')
                    ->where('status',1)
                    ->whereIn('customers_id', Customer::select('id')
                        ->where('customers.sale_mans_id',$reqSalemanId))),
            'return_qty' => Stock::selectRaw('SUM(stock_value)*-1')
                ->whereColumn('stocks.product_types_id','product_types.id')
                ->whereRaw('stock_value < 0')
                ->where('stock_type','return')
                ->whereBetween('stock_date',[$reqFromDate,$reqToDate])
                ->whereIn('id', Bill::select('stocks_id')
                    ->where('status',1)
                    ->whereIn('customers_id', Customer::select('id')
                        ->where('customers.sale_mans_id',$reqSalemanId))),
        ])->where('product_types.status',1)->get()
```

its working but i want to get only **sale_qty > 0** so  when set sale_qty query in where clause then getting error
i want to correct this query

```
Product_Type::addSelect([
            'p_name' => Product::select('p_name')->whereColumn('products.id','product_types.products_id'),
            'product_types.pt_name',
            'sale_qty' => Stock::selectRaw('SUM(stock_value)*-1')
                ->whereColumn('stocks.product_types_id','product_types.id')
                ->whereRaw('stock_value < 0')
                ->where('stock_type','sale')
                ->whereBetween('stock_date',[$reqFromDate,$reqToDate])
                ->whereIn('id', Bill::select('stocks_id')
                    ->where('status',1)
                    ->whereIn('customers_id', Customer::select('id')
                        ->where('customers.sale_mans_id',$reqSalemanId))),
            'return_qty' => Stock::selectRaw('SUM(stock_value)*-1')
                ->whereColumn('stocks.product_types_id','product_types.id')
                ->whereRaw('stock_value < 0')
                ->where('stock_type','return')
                ->whereBetween('stock_date',[$reqFromDate,$reqToDate])
                ->whereIn('id', Bill::select('stocks_id')
                    ->where('status',1)
                    ->whereIn('customers_id', Customer::select('id')
                        ->where('customers.sale_mans_id',$reqSalemanId))),
        ])->where('product_types.status',1)
        ->whereRaw(Stock::selectRaw('SUM(stock_value)*-1')
            ->whereColumn('stocks.product_types_id','product_types.id')
            ->whereRaw('stock_value < 0')
            ->where('stock_type','sale')
            ->whereBetween('stock_date',[$reqFromDate,$reqToDate])
            ->whereIn('id', Bill::select('stocks_id')
                ->where('status',1)
                ->whereIn('customers_id', Customer::select('id')
                    ->where('customers.sale_mans_id',$reqSalemanId))) > 0)->get()
```

in MySQL query which show correct result as per my requirements

```
SELECT 
(SELECT p_name FROM products WHERE id=product_types.products_id) AS p_name, 
pt_name, 
(SELECT SUM(stock_value)*-1 FROM stocks WHERE product_types_id=product_types.id AND stock_value < 0 AND stock_type='sale' AND stock_date BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-08-31' AND id IN (SELECT stocks_id FROM bills WHERE status=1 AND customers_id IN (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE sale_mans_id=1))) AS sale_qty, 
(SELECT SUM(stock_value)*-1 FROM stocks WHERE product_types_id=product_types.id AND stock_value < 0 AND stock_type='return' AND stock_date BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-08-31' AND id IN (SELECT stocks_id FROM bills WHERE status=1 AND customers_id IN (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE sale_mans_id=1))) AS return_qty 
FROM product_types 
WHERE 
status =1 AND 
(SELECT SUM(stock_value)*-1 FROM stocks WHERE product_types_id=product_types.id AND stock_value < 0 AND stock_type='sale' AND stock_date BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-08-31' AND id IN (SELECT stocks_id FROM bills WHERE status=1 AND customers_id IN (SELECT id FROM customers WHERE sale_mans_id=1))) > 0;
```

because where clause not allow without column name so how manage without column name

Answer (score 2):

You can use `->whereRaw` and define the condition as you like. It will be inserted as a string to the full query without any modifications. This way you have total control over it.

Check the related documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw

Comment: ->WhereRaw() already used but getting error

Comment: what is the error?

one of the problems could be, that you specify only the column name in your whereRaw calls but you use several tables in your total query.

have you tried to prefix the column name with the table name?

like: `->whereRaw('stocks.stock_value < 0')`

Comment: i cann't pass column name because i m getting count from another table column SUM so m set condition on behalf of query result.
query error
{message: "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to int",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\testing\\projectSale\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\SalaryController.php"
line: 56
message: "Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder could not be converted to int"
trace: [,…]